# How to find the page number a record is in, in a set of paged records

Tags: t-sql

I have paged SQL query that is like this

```
  SELECT cistranm.transactionid AS transactionid
    ,cistranm.TransactionGroupId AS TransactionGroupId
    ,cisdata.id AS dCPrimaryKey
FROM dbo.cismiscalculations AS calc
INNER JOIN dbo.cismisdata AS cisdata ON calc.cismisdataid = cisdata.id
INNER JOIN dbo.cistransactionmessage AS cistranm ON cisdata.cistransactionmsgid = cistranm.id
INNER JOIN dbo.cistransactionmessagestatus AS cistrans ON cistranm.id = cistrans.cistransactionmessageid
WHERE convert(DATE, cistranm.transactioncompletiontimestamp) = convert(DATE, @LastRunDateTime)
ORDER BY cistranm.transactioncompletiontimestamp
    ,calc.id
    ,calc.earneddate offset(@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsOfPage rows
```

Here I supply the PageNumber and the expected rows per page (Page number can be 1 through 10, expected rows is always 1000)

Lets say on page 5 I have a transactionid as abc123. How can modify this query to return me the page number "5" if I supply the transactionId ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you want to add `Row_Number` to the _select list_ with the same order as the `order by` clause that you'll be removing. A little arithmetic should be able to derive the page number from the row number. Then `select` the desired row from that collection. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Minimize the extraneous shrubbery, show what you've tried, ... .

Answer (score 0):

For those looking but not sure what/where to ask this is how you can find what page a paged record might be in

```
FLOOR(CAST((CAST(T.row_num as decimal) / CAST(@RowsOfPage as decimal)) as decimal)) as page_num
FROM
(
    SELECT...
```